# Merge Two DateTime types in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

This is what I have so far.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the date.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">The date: 05/07/2009</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static DateTime GetDate(string date)
{
    DateTime postDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
    postDate.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow.Hour);
    postDate.AddMinutes(DateTime.UtcNow.Minute);
    postDate.AddSeconds(DateTime.UtcNow.Second);
    postDate.AddMilliseconds(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);

    return postDate;
}
```

Is there a better way to merge two dates? I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return DateTime.Parse(date) + DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the date.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">The date: 05/07/2009</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static DateTime GetDate(string date)
{
    DateTime postDate = DateTime.Parse(date);        
    return postDate.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay);        
}
```

MSDN Link: [DateTime.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx)

EDIT : Code change

Comment: This answer is incorrect. DateTime is an immutable struct; the Add method does not modify the DateTime, but instead returns a new one!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how adding 2 dates makes any sense. Could you give an example how yesterday + now = something? Adding a TimeSpan would make sense: Yesterday + 1 day = today.

Could you explain exactly what you want? The date you parse is actually a TimeSpan? Then you should do:

return DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.parse(timespanstring))